# Getting an access token from the Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to display facebook status updates for a sports team on their website using the facebook graph api, but can't seem to get a valid access token.

Here's my code.

```
require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '123123123123',
    'app_secret' => 'fghdfghtyjdfghdghjfghjfghj', 
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('123123123123|dfhjfgytdfghdfhgdsfjd');

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in.
} else {
    echo 'access token not set - THIS IS WHERE I ALWAYS SEEM TO END UP';
}
exit;
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the code according to permissions first? something like: $permissions = ['manage_pages, publish_actions'];
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(URL::to('/your-redirect-url'), $permissions);

Comment: Potentially not... all the code I'm using is shown here...

Comment: If the page is public, then you can use your app access token to request the data. Otherwise, you will need to get a page access token, or a user access token for a user that is able to see the page. More about the different kinds of tokens and how to get them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Btw., trying to use the canvasHelper here doesn’t make any sense, if I understood correctly you are not even _on_ canvas, but the app is on an external website.

Comment: @CBroe If I'm honest I'm coming at this with limited knowledge of what I've got to do (as if that wasn't already obvious), so I'm just trying a bit of everything until I get some results! I'll check out the link you suggest though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in a Laravel 4 app to connect. Basically when the user clicks on a 'Log in' button, 
1- Create the Facebook instance with app_id, app_secret and default_graph_version. 
2- Get a redirectLoginHelper object to get a loginUrl with a code that facebook will provide  when you call $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, (array) $permissionsNeeded)
3- Redirect to that url
4- Create facebook instance and getRedirectLoginHelper again as step 1 and 2
5- Check if you received the 'code' parameter in the url the helped returned
6- Get the access token: $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken()

In the code I'm providing, I do all this steps in one method. I check if there's a code parameter in the request, if not I request it and redirect. The next time the code runs, when I check if code is there, it continues to the next step

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'facebook_app_id',
    'app_secret' => 'facebook_app_secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if(Input::get('code') == '') {
    $permissions = ['manage_pages, publish_actions'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://yoururl.dev/uri', $permissions);

    return Redirect::to($loginUrl);
}

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    //Handle error
}
```

In this case, the Log in button goes to www.domain.app/connect, the URL that the redirectLoginHelper returns is the same, but with the code parameter: www.domain.app/connect?code=ntasd341251